# string relation with '\0'

Tags: c, string

as far as i know, that every string always terminated with '\0',

so my question is

```
int main()
{   
    char string1[6]="hello";
   // char string2[5]="hello"; // doesnt work

    printf("%d",strlen(string));

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

1. why when i check the length of string1, it shows 5 not 6,which is mean that '\0' doesn't in count, but the array itself count '\0', only allow us to declare  at least string[6] not string[5]? is there any further explanation about this?
2. is there any special case that we are able to end string without '\0'?

Comment: If you read the [strlen man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) you would see: "The strlen() function calculates the length of the string s, *excluding the terminating null byte*" (emphasis mine).

Comment: The C standard says (in §7.1.1 _Definitions of terms_ in the library section: _A_ string _is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character. […] A pointer to a string is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed)
character. The length of a string is the number of bytes preceding the null character […]_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C style strings are traditionally stored with a null terminator.  Functions like `strlen()` do not count this null terminator, and give you the "human" length of the string, e.g. "hello" is length 5.

However, you are welcome to store strings without the null terminator if you want; some systems use strings with length prefixes instead, for example, or use strings of fixed capacity with space padding, or other schemes.  C doesn't prevent you from doing these things, but if you do, you won't be able to use functions like `strlen()` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Use of the terminating null character allows a program to determine where a string ends. If you didn't have the null terminator, you can determine the length of a string either using a different string terminating character or store the length of the string in the string. Using `'\0'` for the terminating null character is most likely historical. That's my guess.

As far as

> is there any special case that we are able to end string without `'\0'`?

No. All of the C library functions that work with strings expect the `'\0'`. Otherwise, they won't be able to determine which element of an array to stop at. As a consequence, they will end up accessing memory out of bounds.

You can create an array of characters that don't have a terminating null character but that won't be a string.

```
char arr[2] = {'a', 'b'};
```

is perfectly fine. You can access `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` without any problem. However, you can't use `arr` as an argument to `strlen`. Doing that will lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the C language [uses '\0'](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#String-Constants) as a sentinel character to find the end of a string. `strlen()` returns the length of the string excluding the null character.

You can automatically create a `char[]` array of the proper size to hold your string constant (including the null character) by omitting the number inside the brackets:

```
char string1[] = "hello";

printf("%d", strlen(string1)); // prints 5
```

This way you can avoid confusion regarding the array length.

To answer question 2: Not if you still want to treat it as a string (i.e. still use the functions in `<string.h>` to manipulate it).